# How do I access CMD opened by .batch?

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd, process

My program so far:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;


const string batDir = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
                        Studio\2019\Professional\Commom7\Tools";
var process = new Process {StartInfo = {WorkingDirectory = batDir, FileName = "VsDevCmd"}};
process.start();

var modules = process.Modules;
foreach (ProcessModule processModule in modules)
{
  //In here you can find the cmd.exe which gets executed by the .batch
  //For example here you could access the memory address of the cmd prompt
}
```

What I want to do is to access the Command Prompt which gets primed and executed by the .batch file which I start. When you give a command to the process like you would do normally it can't detect it because the command is getting executed before the .batch has primed the cmd-Prompt to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

To attach to a existing console automaticly a console program must be started by a program attached to that console.

For a program started by a GUI program

If a console program will be given a new console.

If a GUI program it will not be given a console, however it can use AttachConsole API call to attach to any console.

Compile as a console program.